# Does ExecuteReader(timeout) method terminate process and close connection?

Tags: .net, methods, executereader

When using ExecuteReader(timeout) method to execute a SP, does it terminate process and close connection?

Answer (score 1):

System.Data.Common.DbCommand and the more specialized System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand **do not** contain an overload with a timeout parameter. There is the parameterless ExecuteReader method and [an overload with a CommandBehavior parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereader%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Some other db providers may have this overload, even though I guess there is no need for that since you can use the [CommandTimeout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the base class System.Data.Common.DbCommand abstract base class.

I guess the behavior you are looking for is:

```
System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = null;
// init command
System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```